The total number of physical states of bosonic open string theory of a given mass
In the light-cone gauge the open string mass-shell condition is (in bosonic string theory) $$\alpha 'M^2 =N-1$$ where $$N=\sum_{i=1}^{24}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha^i_{-n}\alpha^{i}_{n}.$$ How can we find out that the number of physical states $d_n$ whose mass is given by $$\alpha 'M^2=n-1$$ is the coefficient of $w^n$ in the power series expansion of $${\rm tr}^N=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{24}{\rm tr}\; w^{\alpha^i_{-n}\alpha^i_n}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-w^n)^{-24}?$$
